# Vbscript, how to write a For loop with two variables

Tags: vb.net, for-loop

I am use Vb to write for loop,
i=1 to 3
j=1 to 3

how to make the i+j result become 1+1,2+2, 3+3.

I know for C#, it can be for(i=0,j=0;i<10,j<10;i++,j++)
just don't know how to write in VB

Comment: VBScript is not VB is not VB.NET. Please clarify exactly what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

<del>Unfortunately, as of March 2022, Microsoft seems to have finally pulled their 25+ year-old VBScript language documentation from their documentation website, [however third-party content-mirrors exist with the documentation for VBScript's `For Next` statement](https://documentation.help/MS-Office-VBScript/vsstmFor.htm)</del>

[As per the VBScript documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/sa3hh43e(v=vs.84))...

**TL;DR:** You can't. VBScript's `For Next` statement only supports updating a **single** variable inside.

You *can* still declare and manually increment your own variables in the loop though, e.g.

Using a single variable:

```vb
Option Explicit

Dim i
For i = 0 To 5 Step 1

    Call DoStuff

Next
```

Using multiple variables requires separate `Dim` declarations and incrementing them inside the `For` loop body:

```vb
Option Explicit

Dim i, j, k
Let j = 0
Let k = 0

For i = 0 To 5 Step 1

    Call DoStuff

    Let j = j + 1
    Let k = k + 1
Next
```

Comment: The [official VBScript documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/t0aew7h6(v=vs.84)) lives on, including the section on the [For...Next](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/sa3hh43e(v=vs.84)) statement.

Comment: @LesFerch Wow, thanks - I spent ages trying to find it and gave up.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim result As Integer
    For i = 1 To 3
        For j = i To i
            result = i + j
            Console.WriteLine(i.ToString + "+" + j.ToString + "=" + result.ToString)
        Next
    Next
```

Comment: If you're going to do this, why even bother with the inner loop?  Just do `Dim j = i` and don't overcomplicate things.

Comment: Hi! Could you elaborate on your answer? thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Or you can also write

```
Dim i, j, result As Integer
    i = 0
    j = 0
    While i < 10 And j < 10
        result = i + j
        Console.WriteLine(i.ToString + "+" + j.ToString + "=" + result.ToString)
        i += 1
        j += 1
    End While
```

If you want to achieve the effect you said, I generally like to use two for loops, and I don't like to use while loops (personal preference).

Comment: This is not VBScript: VBScript does not support static types so using `As Integer` is a syntax error, and `.ToString` is only in VB.NET: it doesn't exist in VBScript nor VB6.